# Undefined variable PHP?

Tags: php, html

I get an error (undefined variable) at line 83 and line 83 is this (inside HTML):

```
<div style="font-size:11px; color:#cc0000; margin-top:10px"><?php echo $error; ?></div>
```

And $error is declared before:

```
$error="Your Login Name or Password is invalid";
```

I tried isset() function but I think I wrong something (I am kinda new in PHP XD)

```
$error=isset("Your Login Name or Password is invalid") ? $_POST["Your Login Name or Password is invalid"] : '';
```

And now I got a fatal error. -.-

Comment: I would suggest not using the ternary operators (?,:) until you have a better grasp of the language - you'll just confuse yourself.

Comment: In the isset function you should pass the variable you want to check if is actually set not a string!

Comment: `isset` is for checking for the presence of variables; `"Your login name..."` is **not** a variable.

Comment: Check for isset construct into manual: http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
<div style="font-size:11px; color:#cc0000; margin-top:10px"><?php if(isset($error)){echo 
$error;} ?></div>
```

Comment: Thank you!! It functions!! :) Why not all the ppl are kind like you? tyvm

Answer (score 0):

`isset()` should be used to check variables.  For example: `isset($error)`

`$_POST` is an array used to access user input submitted via a form.  The indices of `$_POST` will be the same as the `name` attribute of your form element.  For example: The value entered in `<input type="password" name="pass" />` would be available in `$_POST['pass']` when the form is submitted, as long as the form's `method` is `post`.

Please include your full code so that we can properly diagnose your issue with the $error variable not being defined.  Note that if it's defined in an `if` statement or within another function it may not be getting set.